# How to manage pages with WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am making a wordpress theme that will make reviews about Movies and TV Shows, My question is that if i want to make a page for the movies, page for the tv show, one for the season, one for the episode.
How can I make that? How shoudl i include the seasons in the tv show page. 
How the_post() Will know whether this items is movie, or season or or ..
Can you please tell me because i kind of sick of thinking about this.
I am looking for an answer that will put my mind at ease.
This question will have downvotes i know but i have no problem because I am learning and asking, and there is nothing wrong with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is create a custom post types.

This [article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/) has a good explanation and shows how to create them, either using a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) or add them manually like so:

```
function create_posttype() {

    register_post_type( 'movies',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movies'),
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

Comment: I do feel that you are the accepted answer, I will give that article a try, Thank you !!!